# Flickr Json call API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api, flickr

can somebody help me with flickr API

I want to to have "sets" list

all information about sets , "ID, name " etc

this call is for special set:

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key="+apiKey+"&photoset_id=62157624713250820&per_page=" + perPage + "&extras=original_format&format=json&jsoncallback=?

"photoset_id=62157624713250820"

Bu I would like to get this "ID" and "Set name" form the Json call feed

Thanks  a lot for helping !

Answer (score 2):

oh, found it , thanks

http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photosets.getList